# When creating a user in AWS IAM I do not see "Select AWS Credential Type*" "Access Key - Programatic Access"

Tags: amazon-web-services, identity-management, access-keys

Expecting to see this (doing a video tutorial):
[image]

I'm now seeing:

[image]

Curious if something changed? If so is the best workaround to add a private key to the user via the user's security tab within IAM?

Comment: your user have permission to create user and grant programatic access?
your account is part of an organization?

Comment: Hi @JonatasDelatorre I'm signed in as root user so I assume yes.

Answer (score 3):

AWS changes all the time!

As per the message in blue, you can generate access keys after you create the user. Go to the **Security credentials** tab on the IAM User.

Comment: Thanks, DUMB question, do I just make up a key?

Comment: No. AWS will generate an Access Key that starts with `AKIA` and a Secret Key. When it provides the Secret Key, that is the only time you can grab it. It is not possible to retrieve the Secret Key at a later time.